# Why do some WebM videos seamlessly loop and others do not?

Tags: html, video

One thing I have noticed is that if you had a video inserted into a webpage like so:

```
<video loop src='video.webm'></video>
```

On videos that have sound, when the video is over and started back to the beginning, there is a short delay.

It also seems that if the WebM has no audio stream in the container, the video loops seamlessly, with no delay between end and beginning.

Why is that?

Comment: Your question really helps me. Same problem with h.264. Probably it's related with decoding acc, or another audio codec.